# Declare multiple Variables, Console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program that computes the difference between non-negative integers.

Input
Each line of the input consists of a pair of integers. Each integer is between 0 and 2^63 −1 (inclusive). The input is terminated by end of file.

Output
For each pair of integers in the input, output one line, containing the absolute value of their difference

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    long A = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    long B = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(A - B));
}
```

But I need to declare both A and B in one line. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: The only way to do that is to read both values and then split them on a delimiter, your current approach is much better

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string[] read = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    long A = long.Parse(read[0]);
    long B = long.Parse(read[1]);

    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(A - B));
}
```